# What to do with smoke getting into ventilation?

Tags: ventilation

I have a ventilation shaft going from around 1.5m up from the ground level outside, directly into my bedroom ceiling. The ventilator is on 24/7 and its my main source of fresh air since I'm underground.

Lately a neighbor has been getting freaky with his fire place a lot and every other day or so, I guess when the winds align just right, I get a good 5 mins of hardcore wood burning smell imported straight into my bedroom.

Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: IS your building an apartment or a part of a house and do you rent it - where is the ventilator shaft (who controls the outside air inlet ? is it more than one unit that it feeds or just you ?

Comment: Apartment. The ventilator, all the pipes and inlet/outlets are all under my control. There are 2 ventilation systems installed inside my walls, the bedroom and office are under one system and the rest of the apartment is under the other one. I don't really care that much about the temporary smells in the rest of the apartment, since I rarely spend time there anyways, I just want to get my bedroom air clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a comment a while ago that suggested using a combination filter and charcoal filter in duct work to eliminate odors. I use them in my home since my wife hates most odors that others don't mind. I buy them from Home Depot and Lowes and the go by the name "The Web Absorber", cost around $10.00, and are a cut to size filter. You could also look in the furnace filter dept. and see if they carry a charcoal furnace filter that you could fit into the fresh air duct. Charcoal should filter out most if not all the odor.

Comment: @dgeorge notice he uses the terminology 1.5m - that means he is most likely not in the USA  so HD and l owes may not be available to the op.

Comment: All righty. They didn't have any activated carbon filters for air in the local hardware store but I got a giant(~5kg) low resistance one meant for water that fits perfectly over the 10cm diameter inlet. We'll see if it works but if not it was just €8 and I can look for something more specific in a bigger store.

Comment: let us know if that works

Comment: @d.george Yea it works. Its been tricky to figure out whether it works or my neighbor has given up burning stuff but today I confirmed it for sure since the street was filled with burning smells when I got home and the air was clean in my apartment. I got real close to the filter, apparently some of the smell comes through but its different, its like smelling an old inactive fire place and disappears around 20cm away from the filter. Regardless, I'm no longer annoyed by my neighbor.